# Mac Gerrit Setup

Tags: mysql, macos, jenkins, gerrit

Trying to install Gerrit on a Mac that has also Jenkins installed. So far:

- Installed MySQL via Brew successfully.
- Added user & db for Gerrit to MySQL.
- D/l of gerrit.war from https://gerrit-releases.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
- Installed gerrit.war into `~/Applications/Gerrit`
- Set `canonicalWebUrl` to `http://localhost:8080/gerrit/` in gerrit.config
- Restart Gerrit with `~/Applications/Gerrit/bin/gerrit.sh restart`

But restart fails. There seems to be no consistent Mac Gerrit setup guide whatsoever and I feel I'm stuck with this issue.

Gerrit error_log says:

```
ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start HTTP daemon
```

Has anyone running this config on a Mac and can give me some help?

Comment: Works for me. Check `logs/error_log`.

Comment: Add the error message found in the GERRIT-SITE/logs/error_log

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira I added the significant line from the error log file.

Comment: I think there're more error messages after these ones, correct?

Comment: Make sure the web-servers (ports) for Gerrit and Jenkins don't collide.

Answer (score 0):

> on a Mac that has also Jenkins installed

Most likely the cause is that Jenkins is already running on the same port (8080). Try to change Gerrit's `canonicalWebUrl` to another port (or change Jenkins' port).